# Replace double quote by single quote into python list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python list that contains data

I need to extract data from the list and get a tring with simple quote (in order to insert values into PGsql later), the problem is that one of my value is in double quote.

```
a = {'one': 'NR', 'two': 'NR', 'three': '-2', 'four': '', 'five': 'NR', 'six': "Hello"}
```

How can I get :

```
a['six'] = 'Hello'
```

I already tried `.replace('"','"')` but it doesn't work.

Thank you

Comment: what did you expect to happen when you try to replace one character with the exact same character? oO

Comment: That looks like a dictionary rather than a list. Whether the variable is assigned with single or double quotation marks makes no difference to the stored string. You may want to show some code to illustrate exactly what you are trying to do and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the output to be in single quote.

Try this : `replace("\"", "\'")`

Comment: What if a[0] = "Let's go" ? I will get a[0].replace("\"", "\'") = 'Let"s go' How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You need escape characters in .replace().
Try this:

```
replace('\'','\"')
```